# iOS Youtube Player : Toggle fullscreen mode of youtube player in iOS using custom controls

Tags: ios, uiwebview, custom-controls, youtube-javascript-api

I have a requirement to create custom controls for Youtube player in iOS. I have used UIWebview to play youtube videos. I have hidden default controls by using `'controls':0` flag. I am able to map all the actions like play, pause etc using youtube's java script api with my UIButtons. But, I am not able to figure out how to toggle full screen mode programatically with my custom button.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Found any solution?

Comment: No @iDroid. Have not found anything.

Comment: Not yet. But I'm searching.